# Как восстановить отображение USB устройств

Tags: ubuntu

Перестал отображаться модем командой dmesg | grep ttyU, хотя командой lsusb его видно. Так же данная проблема образовалась после обновления и перезагрузки компьютера 15 марта 2019. (Система Ubuntu 16.04). Кто решил данную проблему - подскажите пожалуйста - какие действия необходимо произвести.

Comment: 1. программа *dmesg* выводит содержимое кольцевого буфера сообщений программы *linux*. буфер этот не безразмерный, новые поступающие сообщения будут затирать старые. отключите и подключите устройство снова — свежие записи попадут в буфер и их можно будет увидеть в выводе программы *dmesg*. 2. ищите в выводе идентификатор вашего usb-устройства и читайте информацию не только в строках, где встретится идентификатор, но и в прилегающих к ним соседних.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, "передёргивал" модем ни один раз (и в другие USB порты втыкал), и перезагружал компьютер ни один раз (включал и выключал). Проблема возникла после установки системных обновлений, такое впечатление что отключилась какая то служба (не стартует при запуске компьютера).

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить проблему обнаружения модемов загрузкой с live cd ubuntu (не важно какой версии), затем не выключая компьютера и не вынимая модемов грузимся с жёсткого диска, и модемы становятся видны.
Предположительно обновления о которых говорилось ранее, запортили что то в самой операционке установленной на ж.диске. Загрузившись с live cd мы сбрасываем некий "флаг" который записан в модеме.